# Is this the correct way to check for clicks on different device sizes in android?

Tags: android

I am creating a game with a main screen having seven buttons
[image]

This is a sample image suppose the blue box is a button positioned anywhere. Form a graphic software i know co-ordinates of top-left and bottom-right corner. I get the co-ordinates of point touched by user like this and show a success toast

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();
    Height_Ratio = height/Background_Height;
    Width_Ratio = width/Background_Width;
    Play_Button_Left_Ratio = Play_Button_Left*Width_Ratio;
    Play_Button_Right_Ratio = Play_Button_Right*Width_Ratio;
    Play_Button_Top_Ratio = Play_Button_Top*Height_Ratio;
    Play_Button_Bottom_Ratio = Play_Button_Bottom*Height_Ratio;
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if(x > Play_Button_Left_Ratio && x < Play_Button_Right_Ratio && y > Play_Button_Top_Ratio && y < Play_Button_Bottom_Ratio)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Height and width for device are obtained using

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

I have to do it for seven buttons is there any more efficient way.Also does above code for getting screen height gives actual pixels or density independent pixels?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use an OnClickListener on the buttons?

Comment: They are not button they are images like the blue box above.They will just function as buttons.

Comment: @user3404195 you can add an OnClickListener on an ImageView, if that is an image view... or what kind of View is it?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();
```

to

```
 int tx = (int) event.getX();
    int ty = (int) event.getY();
```

to avoid confusing variables

in your touch

```
if(tx>image.x&&tx<image.x+image.width&&ty>image.y&&ty<image.y+image.height){
//image clicked do something
}
```